# Plotly: Range slider not being displayed for row count > 500

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, customization, plotly-python

[image]

As is visible from the image, the scaffolding for the rangeslider is generated but the trace inside it is not. It is also fully functional otherwise. With some experiment, I found that only if you set the no. of rows to 500 or less, it displays correctly. Is there a way to display it for rows more than that? Here is the code to reproduce-

```
size = 501 #change this to change no. of rows

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = {'date': pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=size, freq='D'),
     'new_cases': np.random.random(size=size),
     'new_cases_smoothed': np.random.random(size=size)}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['new_cases','new_cases_smoothed'])
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True),type="date"))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in **graph_objects**

```
size = 501 #change this to change no. of rows

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = {'date': pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=size, freq='D'),
     'new_cases': np.random.random(size=size),
     'new_cases_smoothed': np.random.random(size=size)}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
# fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['new_cases','new_cases_smoothed'])
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df["date"], y=df[c], name=c) for c in ['new_cases','new_cases_smoothed']])
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"rangeslider":{"visible":True},"type":"date",
                        "range":[df.tail(50)["date"].min(),df.tail(50)["date"].max()]})
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll holdout a bit longer for a plotly express answer. If there's none, I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 5):

For others using `plotly.express`, I had luck setting the kwarg `render_mode='webg1'`:

```
size = 501 #change this to change no. of rows

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = {'date': pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=size, freq='D'),
     'new_cases': np.random.random(size=size),
     'new_cases_smoothed': np.random.random(size=size)}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['new_cases','new_cases_smoothed'], render_mode='webg1')
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True),type="date"))
fig.show()
```

Comment: As pointed by @matgc, there is a typo here (`webg1` instead of `webgl`). It seems to work with any value in render_mode. Funny enough, but `render_mode="dummy"` also works.... Note that this also works with the [plotly backend directy](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/) : `fig = df.plot(x="date", y=["new_cases", "new_cases_smoothed"], render_mode="dummy")`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, you typed WEBG1 instead of WEBGL and it worked.
If you input WEBGL it doesn't work.
In fact if you type anything that should not be accepted as valid such as just blank (render_mode='') it works as well.

Go figure...

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. We you have enough reputation, you can comment on posts. Please read [answer].

Comment: True enough, but this comment is still usefull. I'll pick it up in the trending answer.